# FreeSSHd + WinSCP: "Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key!"

Tags: ssh, winscp

I'm trying to gain access to my Windows 2008 R2 server via SSH. I have a Remote Desktop connection, but I need to upload my files to the server. For SSH servers on the Windows server, I've tried Cygwin+OpenSSH, but that only starts around one in twenty times that I try it, so I've installed FreeSSHd and start it up manually. FreeSSHd generated a private key called "RSAKey.cfg" when I installed it, and I tried copying this into a file and converting it to .ppk using PuTTYgen on my PC so that it might work with WinSCP or the FileZilla client. I made a user that can use Shell, SFTP, or Tunnel, and is set to authenticate with public key authentication, but when I try to login as `SFTPuser@[IPAddress]`, I get the following error in WinSCP:

> Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key!

Questions:

1. What does this mean?
2. What is the correct procedure for getting a matching public/private key pair to work with each other in FileZilla + WinSCP?

Comment: I'm running into the same wall.  I found this which might be of help: http://wthwdik.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/how-to-get-freesshd-public-key-authentication-to-work/ -- Additionally, you are probably already aware: in your local desktop you can select files, CTRL+C to copy them, and then in RDP, use CTRL+V to paste them -- this is very insecure however, so you may want to put the files into an encrypted archive file first, etc...

Comment: Had the same with KypM SSH server on Windows - problem was solved with proper configuration of public/private keys. Log of KTS helped a lot. [Link to question on KTS forum](http://www.kpym.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?t=545).

Answer (score 0):

I've found that I get that error when connecting to FreeSSHd server if it's not running as an administrator.